# Windows 32-bit Eclipse installed on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I have Windows 32-bit Eclipse installed on a 64-bit OS? I have some plugins which works only on 32-bit Eclipse so shall I install the 32-bit Eclipse? And what about my JAVA then? Should I have Windows x86 or Windows x64?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: Why dont you try? As far as I know Eclipse is just a zip package so all you need to do is unzip and try and run it

Comment: You know, one of the great attributes of Java is the portability between different OSes and hardware architectures? Also, Windows 7 supports executing 32-bit applications in a 64-bit environment w/o problems.

Answer (score 7):

You can install 32bit Eclipse on 64bit Windows without an issue.

The Windows OS has facilities to deal with 32bit processes.

Comment: AFAIK You can run almost any 32-bit program on a 64-bit OS (inc flavours of Unix) You can't run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Should I be worried about my JDK installed in the system? I installed jdk-7u7-windows-x64.exe for my 64-bit OS? Hope its fine ??

Comment: @CareerAspirant - Should be fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! Great help here!

Comment: Now I get this error "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:/JDK/bin/client/jvm.dll" while opening my Eclipse! Guess this has something to do with JDK installed ? Any suggestions

Comment: @CareerAspirant - Chances are that the 32bit Eclipse can't use the 64bit libraries directly. You really should be matching the libraries with the application. Try installing the 32bit JDK, or use a 64bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You'll need to install the 32 bit version of the JDK and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to it.  Then you can start Eclipse by specifying the java VM in eclipse.ini or via a batch script.

```
@echo off
start "Eclipse %WORKSPACE%" eclipse.exe -data %WORKSPACE% -vm "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw.exe"
```